# foreach loop not being entered

Tags: php, foreach

This isn't very clear to me. I'm never entering this loop:

```
            // Insert the custom submission data
            foreach ($submissionDetail['submission'] as $submissionItem)
            {
                 // Code here
            }
```

I am using PhpStorm, so I step through the code and I can see that evaluating `$submissionDetail['submission']` shows an array with 14 elements.

So I can't see why it would skip the foreach loop?

Comment: Post your array structure

Comment: As it turned out, there was a `break` in the if statement directly above this. I was so puzzled about the actual foreach loop I wasn't looking above it... Sorry for wasting everyone's time; I should not have made this mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying this that loop is not entering then `$submissionDetail` is one dimensional array, make sure and check if that `$submissionDetail` is two dimensional array.
    You might be trying to do this:

```
 foreach ($submissionDetail as $submissionItem)
    {
                     // Code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If $submissionDetail['submission'] is array, then it must be entered in the loop.

Yet you check:

```
if(is_array($submissionDetail['submission'])){

 foreach ($submissionDetail['submission'] as $submissionItem)
            {
                .......................
            }
}
```